# Why do I get this error? void* is not a pointer to object type.

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, g++

```
void *stackAddr[NUM_THREADS];

stackAddr[i] = malloc(STACKSIZE);
```

The compiler (g++ 4.4.3) complains where the malloc is called...

```
warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic
error: ‘void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type
```

If you are interested in seeing the whole code, here it goes...

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 4

void *stackAddr[NUM_THREADS];
pthread_t thread[NUM_THREADS];
pthread_attr_t attr;

void *BusyWork(void *t)
{
   int i;
   long tid;
   double result=0.0;
   tid = (long)t;

   printf("Thread %ld starting...\n",tid);
   for ( i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
   {
      result = result + sin(i*tid) * tan(i*tid);
   }
   printf("Thread %ld done. Result = %e\n", tid, result);
   pthread_exit((void*) t);
}

void pthread_create_with_stack( pthread_t * pthread, void *(*start_routine) (void *), int tid )
{
    const size_t STACKSIZE = 0xC00000; //12582912
    void *stackAddr;
    int rc;
    size_t i;
    pthread_t thread;
    pid_t pid;

    stackAddr[tid] = malloc(STACKSIZE); // Error here!
    pthread_attr_setstack(&attr, stackAddr[tid], STACKSIZE);

    rc = pthread_create( pthread, &attr, start_routine, (void*)tid );
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int rc;
   long t;
   void *status;

   /* Initialize and set thread detached attribute */
   pthread_attr_init(&attr);
   pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

   for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++) 
   {
      printf("Main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
      rc = pthread_create_with_stack(&thread[t], BusyWork, t); 
      if (rc) 
      {
         printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
         exit(-1);
      }
   }

   /* Free attribute and wait for the other threads */
   pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
   for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++) 
   {
      rc = pthread_join(thread[t], &status);
      if (rc) 
      {
         printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_join() is %d\n", rc);
         exit(-1);
      }
      printf("Main: completed join with thread %ld having a status"   
            "of %ld\n",t,(long)status);
    }

    printf("Main: program completed. Exiting.\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Which line of code produces that error?  The `malloc` line?

Comment: Show the actual code, there is no error here.

Comment: @trojanfoe, yes, the malloc line.

Comment: @Daniel, why use char* when I actually require void*.

Comment: The error is not in this code. Is the real code doing something like trying to add an offset to the result of `malloc()`?

Comment: We are **not** interested in seeing the whole code. We **are** interested in seeming a complete, minimal sample program that demonstrates the error. If you had reduced your program to smallest possible program that shows the error, you very likely would have found the problem yourself. This is an essential debugging skill; it allows you to solve your own problem, and it increases the effectiveness of the help you receive when you get stuck. See http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are declaring a local variable `void *stackAddr`, which shadows the global `stackAddr` array.

Moreover, it is not an array, and applying the `[]` subscript operator attempts to offset and dereference a `void` pointer, hence the compile error.

Dereferencing and pointer-arithmetic on void pointers is not permitted by the standard since `sizeof(void)` is undefined.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: Yes you are. `pthread_create_with_stack` has a local variable `void *stackAddr`.

Comment: How are you "not doing any such thing" when in fact you are exactly doing such a thing?

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks for your answers! Kerrek SB, Blagvoest has actually now changed his answer. I commented on his previous answer.

Answer (score 4):

You messed up your declaration:

```
void *stackAddr;
```

should be:

```
void *stackAddr[];
```

(You may also need to set a size for the array.)

Then you try to do this:

```
stackAddr[tid] = malloc(STACKSIZE);
```

So you're accessing an array element of a `void*`.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: no you don't. At least I know who's doing those wonderful -1-s..

Comment: Take a closer look at your `pthread_create_with_stack` function. You're missing the `[]` in your declaration.

Comment: @yi_H, hahaha, sorry man, deleted my comment, and upvoted it. Mystical was commenting on the local stackAddr, while I was looking at the global one, which is declared as an array. Actually the local one was the problem, which needs to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Now you've posted the real code, I'm guessing the error is in `pthread_create_with_stack`, where you have a local variable `void * stackAddr` that hides the global array.

It looks like you should just remove the local variable.

Answer (score 2):

What you posted first, is *not* a problem.

```
void *stackAddr[NUM_THREADS];
```

But in the code you have something else:

```
void *stackAddr;
```

so the compiler tries to use that local variable, and of course fails to compile..

Answer (score 2):

In `pthread_create_with_stack`, you have this code:

```
void *stackAddr;
...
stackAddr[tid] = malloc(STACKSIZE)
```

The expression `stackAddr[tid]`  tries to do arithmetic on a `void*`.

Answer (score 0):

In the version you posted, `stackAddr` isn't an array, yet you're assigning to `stackAddr[tid]`.  The compiler replaces this with `*(stackAddr + tid)` with the parenthetical expression evaluating to `stackAddr + tid * sizeof(void)`, so the compiler warns you about `sizeof(void)`.

Comment: The compiler knows the size and alignment of all complete types, including `void*`. Judging from the variable names, the OP needs the array to keep track of a number of blocks of memory to be used as thread stacks.

Comment: All this is clearly specified by the standard: `void*` is large enough to hold any object pointer. Alignment isn't part of the language. You need void pointers precisely for the result of calls to `malloc()` or `::operator new()`.

Comment: `void *` will be the same size as, say, `char *` and alignment has nothing to do with it.  `malloc()` returns `void *` so what is the problem?  I cannot see it myself.

Comment: OK, I'll try to keep this in mind, though it's very rare that I deal with `void *`s directly.  Thanks for the clarification.  I wrote my original comment as a guess at what the compiler was complaining about before the new code (with the new declaration inside the function) was posted.  I updated my guess to just explain the warning, but of course other answers here truly cover what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ void pointers have no attributes, that includes size.  As a result, you cannot calculate the offset address for i-number voids from the beginning of the array.  It is the specification of a particular index in the array is causing your math issues.